# Python: struggling converting .txt file with unicode characters

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8, text-processing

I have a large `raw_data.txt` file with twitter data.

As an example, a short raw_data.txt file with two tweets would be:

```
Won the match #getin . Plus, tomorrow is a very busy day, with Awareness Day\u2019s and debates. Gulp. Debates...
I\u2019m sorry\u002c I Heart Paris is no longer available at the Rockwell branch!
```

I want to read this file with unicode characters and save the data in a new `output.txt` in the following format:

```
Won the match #getin . Plus, tomorrow is a very busy day, with Awareness Day’s and debates. Gulp. Debates...
I’m sorry, I Heart Paris is no longer available at the Rockwell branch!
```

I'm currently getting the exact string in utf-8 encoding.
I've tried many things without success (encodings-decodings).

The code I'm using is the following:

```
f = open('raw_data.txt', "r")
output_file = open('tweets-cleaned.txt', 'w')
for line in f:
  # encode/decode
  # text = line.encode.....decode....
  # finish encode/decode
  output_file.write(f'{text}\r\n')

output_file.close()
f.close()
```

Comment: You could use the `encoding` parameter when using the `open()` command. (`open(fileName, "w", encoding = "utf-8"`)

Comment: Yeah I've tried this, and didn't work

Comment: This looks like badly processed JSON data (but it could be something else too). If there are escape sequences in plain text (ie. literally a backslash, a "u" and four digits), then those are there; decoding won't help. You can try Python's "unicode_escape" codec (described [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#text-encodings)), but it might not work properly and you might end up writing regex-replace fun code, if you can't fix the source.

Comment: You should specify encoding on both `open`. Then you can forget encode/decode part [it is automatically done]. The rule: encode/decode just at IO-interface. Also your `\r\n` smell. And you are probably doing in the inverse way with encode/decode. Or maybe you want all control [it is bad], so read and write files as binary (and so you see you should decode and then encode), and so you can specify explicitly your wanted CRLF end of line

Comment: Yes, it seems those escape sequences are there and I can't do anything. However I've checked all the cases and I can create a dictionary and simply replace the character. Ex: ```text="something\u002c something more``` -- ```text.replace('\u002c', ',')```